# True/False in measure theory. Is my counterexample wrong?

Tags: measure-theory

> T/F, if $f$ is (Lesbegue) integrable and nonnegative, then $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f = 0.$

Isn't this false for the indicator function? This is in the Riemannian case...

Unless I missed something here. Isn't this false in general? How does integrablity maybe make this true?

Comment: The limit need not exist, as you can change $f$ on a set of measure zero without changing the integral...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the indicator function" though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Think about a continuous function that is zero everywhere except for triangles centered on the integers $n$, height $+1$ with area $2^{-|n|}$.

Comment: Okay but I am asking if my answer right...?

Comment: Echoing Seth, what do you mean by the indicator function here?

Comment: So something like a step function. Let's say $f = 1$ on even integers and $f = 0$ on odd integers (so this is integrable). That's the idea. Or something like $f = 1 + \sin x$.

Comment: Oh wait, actually neither are integrable.

Comment: So I am wrong, woops. Your example is better.

Comment: The triangles example works because this is clearly positive and the areas go to zero so it is integrable but the limit as $x\to \infty$ does not exist because the "limit" on the integers will be $1$ and the "limit" on the nonintegers goes to zero.

Comment: Wait, what's the length of the base for your triangles?  $2^{|n| -1}$?

Comment: $A = \frac{1}{2}bh$, so $b = 2^{-|n|+1}$, howsoever you want to place the base (centered on $n$, immediately after $n$, ...). I would also exclude a triangle at $n=0$ for neatness.